# Displaying data from Firebase onto HTML Webpage

Tags: database, firebase

I am able to pull data from firebase and show it in the browser console, but how do I actually display it as text on a webpage?

Here's the code I have now:

```html
<script>
        

  var ref = new Firebase("https://datatest-104.firebaseio.com");
 ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo("United States").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.key());
 });

  //My code that I'm trying:
  document.write(snapshot.key());
  
 
    </script>
```

I am trying to use document.write(snapshot.key()); but am not sure how it works.

Comment: I recommend that you take this 5 minute interactive tutorial: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/. After that any tutorial on "building single-page web applications" is probably a good next stop.

Comment: Hi Frank, yes, I did the tutorial, but could you point me to how to display the contents of the database in a webpage? The chat display message is not clear enough for this example. Thanks!

Comment: The Firebase tutorial shows one common way of putting the content into the page (using jQuery). There are other ways, but there are tons of tutorials for those. But recommending such resources is off-topic here at StackOverflow. From the "rules": "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `document.write(snapshot.key());`into the function instead of out of it:

```html
ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo("United States").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   document.write(snapshot.key());
 });
```

Then, the `snapshot`will be defined, so it'll write onto the page.